# Need column names and column values from update sql before executing

Tags: java, sql

I need to know the list of the column and values from the update sql using java. Code is to read a update query and take backup of the actual column values before executing the update sql. For this is need to know the column names. Please advise!

sql = update testenv.employee set gender = '2',StudentInd = '112233' where empID in (987987);

```
String criteriaQuery = resultset.getString("query"); // this is the update statement which is not constant and varies everytime.
```

String schema = StringUtils.substringBetween(criteriaQuery.toUpperCase(), "UPDATE ", ".").trim();
`String table = StringUtils.substringBetween(criteriaQuery.toUpperCase(), ".", "SET").trim();`
`String columnName = StringUtils.substringBetween(criteriaQuery.toUpperCase(), "SET", "=").trim();`

But columnName will not get the correct columns. Need to optimise the code such that i can get the entire column names from the update query.

Comment: I need java code to achieve this.

Comment: Can you execute a `SELECT` statement first and get the details, save them, and the execute your `UPDATE` statement after that? You can learn how to do that from any JDBC tutorial.

Comment: Yea, i need to execute select statement, for which i need to know the columns which i have been instructed to update. The requirement is update statement would be provided, java code must read the statement and get the col names and table name from the update query and then using select statement code will backup the actual data. Once backup is done, the update query will be executed.

Comment: Please update your post with the code that you allready have, and try to provide some context in your question.

Comment: It sounds like you need to parse the `UPDATE` statement and pull out the column names. How you do that depends on how much the `UPDATE` statement varies.

Comment: String criteriaQuery = resultset.getString("query"); // this is the update statement which is not constant and varies everytime.
String schema = StringUtils.substringBetween(criteriaQuery.toUpperCase(), "UPDATE ", ".").trim();
String table = StringUtils.substringBetween(criteriaQuery.toUpperCase(), ".", "SET").trim();
String columnName = StringUtils.substringBetween(criteriaQuery.toUpperCase(), "SET", "=").trim();

But columnName will not get the correct columns. Need to optimise the code such that i can get the entire column names from the update query.

Comment: Can you restructure your original question and include the code in a code block so it's not so hard to read? You can edit your question. A vague question with unformatted code in comments is pretty difficult to answer properly. Help us help you! :)

Comment: Sorry Matt, i m new to raise any questions. So cudnt format my code!

Comment: You may create trigger for update and(or delete)

Comment: I think you could rephrase your question in terms of string parsing. You have an `UPDATE` statement. You need to extract column names from it. None of the other information is useful. What is important is how much the `UPDATE` statement can vary. I assume your current code only extracts the word `gender` as a column name because you are looking for what's between `SET` and `=`. Maybe you could look for what's between `SET` and `WHERE` which includes all the column / value pairs.

Comment: Thanks matt! I got it the way u said using map.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JDBC, you can use the following:

```
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
```

after getting the result set of your select statement.
http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/DiscriptionTable.shtml
Provides a clear example, the same applies for SQLServer databases and Oracle.